# In JavaScript, where does "constructor" come from?

Tags: javascript

The following snippet of code is taken from Eloquent JavaScript.

```
var noCatsAtAll = {};
if ("constructor" in noCatsAtAll)
  console.log("Yes, there definitely is a cat called 'constructor'.");
```

I find it quite mystifying. Why does the 'if' return true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All instances of Object have a `constructor` property that specifies the function that constructs the Object's prototype.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Properties_2

The `in` operator looks at *all* properties, including inherited ones. If you only want to see the properties on the object itself, you can use `hasOwnProperty`:

```
var a = {};
"constructor" in a; // true
a.hasOwnProperty("constructor"); // false
```

Note that while the `in` operator sees `"constructor"`, a `for (key in a)` loop wouldn't. This is because the `"constructor"` property is non-enumerable.

Answer (score 6):

JavaScript objects have a function called `constructor` which is the function that created the object's instance. It's built-in to all objects. The `in` operator tests for the presence of *something* called "constructor" in the instance of your dictionary, so it returns true. The same thing would happen if you tested for `length`, for example.

Answer (score 2):

It is the constructor of the `Object` type.  A reference to the [`constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) function is available directly on that property ("constructor") of an object (it applies to constructors you write too).

In turn, the names of properties present are [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) objects.

Answer (score 1):

`constructor` is a method of `Object`.  You can find the `constructor` method throughout all objects unless you modify it. The `in` operator will find methods through the `prototype` chains. Which is is why it's recommended to use `hasOwnProperty` to test for properties in your own objects.

```
    var noCatsAtAll = {};
    if ("constructor" in noCatsAtAll)
      console.log("Yes, there definitely is a cat called 'constructor'.");

    if ('constructor' in Object)
       console.log("Yes, there is also a method called constructor");

    var noCon = Object.create(null); // create a completetly empty object
    console.log('constructor' in noCon); // false

    function hasConstructorToo() {}

    console.log('constructor' in hasConstructorToo) // true
    console.log('constructor' in []); // true
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xsb3E/3`